# Authorization for pkrange query on CosmosDB REST API

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cosmosdb

For a testing scenario, I'd like to run a Stored Procedure against each partition in a CosmosDB database, and I'm attempting to get the list of partition ranges from CosmosDB using PowerShell.

I'm getting a 401 - Unauthorized response for this query, but other queries on the same collection work fine - for example executing a procedure works.

The code I'm using to query the ranges is:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web 

# Configure as required
$accountName  = ""
$connectionKey = ""
$collectionName = ""
$databaseName = ""

function GetKey([System.String]$Verb = '',[System.String]$ResourceId = '',
                [System.String]$ResourceType = '',[System.String]$Date = '',
                [System.String]$masterKey = '')
{
    $keyBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($masterKey) 
    $text = @($Verb.ToLowerInvariant() + "`n" + 
        $ResourceType.ToLowerInvariant() + "`n" + $ResourceId + "`n" + 
        $Date.ToLowerInvariant() + "`n" + "" + "`n")
    $body =[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($text)
    $hmacsha = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 -ArgumentList (,$keyBytes) 
    $hash = $hmacsha.ComputeHash($body)
    $signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hash)

    [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($('type=master&ver=1.0&sig=' + $signature))
}

function GetUTDate() {
    $date = get-date
    $date = $date.ToUniversalTime();
    return $date.ToString("r", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture);
}       

function BuildHeaders([string]$action = "get",[string]$resType, [string]$resourceId){
    $authz = GetKey -Verb $action -ResourceType $resType -ResourceId $resourceId -Date $apiDate -masterKey $connectionKey
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("Authorization", $authz)
    $headers.Add("x-ms-version", '2017-02-22')
    $headers.Add("x-ms-date", $apiDate) 
    $headers.Add("Cache-Control", 'no-cache') 
    $headers.Add("Accept", 'application/json')
    $headers.Add("Content-Type", 'application/json')
    $headers
}

function GetPartitionKeys(){
    $pkranges = "dbs/" + $databaseName + "/colls/" + $collectionName + "/pkranges"
    $headers = BuildHeaders -action Get -resType colls -resourceId $pkranges

    $uri = $rootUri + "/" + $pkranges

    write-host "Calling" $uri
    write-host($headers|Out-String)

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers
}

$rootUri = "https://" + $accountName + ".documents.azure.com"
GetPartitionKeys
```

I think the problem is to do with the Resource Type when I'm building the Auth header but the CosmosDB REST documentation doesn't have much information about querying this resource. At present I'm getting the following output:

```
Calling https://my-account-name.documents.azure.com/dbs/my-db-name/colls/my-coll-name/pkranges

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Answer (score 0):

When computing the has for the authorization header the ResourceType value should be "pkranges".

The ResourceLink would be "dbs/my-db-name/colls/my-coll-name" and the URL you request is: https://my-account-name.documents.azure.com/dbs/my-db-name/colls/my-coll-name/pkranges

Answer (score -1):

Paul- Stored procedures can be executed only against a partition key, not against individual partition key ranges.

Comment: Hi Mimi, yes, I'm able to run my Stored Procedure if I specify a partition key that I know exists. However I need to programmatically find a key for each partition then run the procedure for each one. My procedure is to delete all data from a collection before automated testing runs (likely under 100 records). Deleting and re-creating the collection is quite temperamental and frequently errors, so I'm trying this route.